# CCMoveTo causing jumps

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a game using Cocos2D and Kobold2D.  In my game, I have a ship that I want to move to where the player taps, using this code:

```
KKInput * input = [KKInput sharedInput];
CGPoint tap = [input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan];
if (tap.x != 0 && tap.y != 0)
{
    [ship stopAllActions]; // Nullifies previous actions
    int addedx = tap.x - ship.position.x;
    int addedy = tap.y - ship.position.y;
    int squaredx = pow(addedx, 2);
    int squaredy = pow(addedy, 2);
    int addedSquares = squaredx + squaredy;
    int distance = pow(addedSquares, 0.5);
    [ship runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:distance/100 position:tap]];//makes ship move at a constant speed
}
```

The ship generally moves as I expect it to.  However, if I tap near the ship, instead of smoothly moving to the tap location, it jumps to that location.  How do I fix this?

Comment: it is because of actionWithDuration, you are providing, in CCMoveTo action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is right but your calculation is lack precision. 
Especially when you calc the fly time as distance/100. That means when distance < 100 the result is 0, so the ship is jumping to the destination.

Basically, you should use float instead of int when dealing with positions in cocos2d. And there are couple functions can do the work nicely.

You may change your code to this:

```
[ship stopAllActions]; // Nullifies previous actions
float distance = ccpDistance(tap, ship.position);
[ship runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:distance/100.0f position:tap]];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All you can use the `ccpDistance` function of cocos2d to calculate distance between two point.
And it jumps because if u tap too near the distance is too small suppose `2 or 10 ...` the you are dividing it on `100`
e.g `5/100 = 0.05` which is too low that's why it jumps.
You need to handle it manually i think some thing like `if(speed<1) speed++;` adding `1` to speed. shortcut solution :)